# webdav, Directory vs Location

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, samba, webdav

I'm in the first steps with webdav. While trying to configure it, seeing other people configurations I found some use the `<Directory>` directive and some use the `<Location>` directive. Some use both, https://hexeract.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/configure-a-webdav-enabled-webserver-for-multiple-user-folders-and-one-shared-folder/.

May I ask a clarification on the purpose of each one?